# Running Celery on AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, celery, supervisord

I've a django application which uses celery which I'm moving onto AWS.  I've upgraded from Python 2.7 to 3.6 at the same time.

I'm having trouble getting celery to run on AWS, with this error:

```
Application deployment failed at 2018-08-06T14:02:02Z with exit status 127 and error: Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/run_supervised_celeryd.sh failed.

[program:django-celery-worker]
; Set full path to celery program if using virtualenv
command=/opt/python/run/venv/bin/python /opt/python/current/app/manage.py celery worker -A myapp --loglevel=INFO

directory=/opt/python/current/app
user=nobody
numprocs=1
stdout_logfile=/var/log/celery-worker.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/celery-worker.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10

; Need to wait for currently executing tasks to finish at shutdown.
; Increase this if you have very long running tasks.
stopwaitsecs = 600

; When resorting to send SIGKILL to the program to terminate it
; send SIGKILL to its whole process group instead,
; taking care of its children as well.
killasgroup=true

; if rabbitmq is supervised, set its priority higher
; so it starts first
priority=998

environment=PYTHONPATH="/opt/python/current/app/:",PATH="/opt/python/run/venv/bin/:%(ENV_PATH)s",RDS_PORT="5432",RDS_PASSWORD="stmtrx321",RDS_DB_NAME="ebdb",RDS_USERNAME="postgres",RDS_HOSTNAME="aan9bvuq3a4wd1.cxzlzbczjyp1.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com"
/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/run_supervised_celeryd.sh: line 47: supervisorctl: command not found
/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/run_supervised_celeryd.sh: line 50: supervisorctl: command not found
/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/run_supervised_celeryd.sh: line 53: supervisorctl: command not found.
Incorrect application version "app-b38e-180802_150757" (deployment 23). Expected version "app-0def-180806_140451" (deployment 26).
```

`supervisor` is installed.

This is my config file:

```
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/run_supervised_celeryd.sh" :
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash

      # Get django environment variables
      celeryenv=`cat /opt/python/current/env | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/export //g' | sed 's/$PATH/%(ENV_PATH)s/g' | sed 's/$PYTHONPATH//g' | sed 's/$LD_LIBRARY_PATH//g'`
      celeryenv=${celeryenv%?}

      # Create celery configuration script
      celeryconf="[program:django-celery-worker]
      ; Set full path to celery program if using virtualenv
      command=/opt/python/run/venv/bin/python /opt/python/current/app/manage.py celery worker -A myapp --loglevel=INFO

      directory=/opt/python/current/app
      user=nobody
      numprocs=1
      stdout_logfile=/var/log/celery-worker.log
      stderr_logfile=/var/log/celery-worker.log
      autostart=true
      autorestart=true
      startsecs=10

      ; Need to wait for currently executing tasks to finish at shutdown.
      ; Increase this if you have very long running tasks.
      stopwaitsecs = 600

      ; When resorting to send SIGKILL to the program to terminate it
      ; send SIGKILL to its whole process group instead,
      ; taking care of its children as well.
      killasgroup=true

      ; if rabbitmq is supervised, set its priority higher
      ; so it starts first
      priority=998

      environment=$celeryenv"

      # Create the celery supervisord conf script
      echo "$celeryconf" | tee /opt/python/etc/celery.conf

      # Add configuration script to supervisord conf (if not there already)
      if ! grep -Fxq "[include]" /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf
        then
        echo "[include]" | tee -a /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf
        echo "files: celery.conf" | tee -a /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf
      fi

      # Reread the supervisord config
      supervisorctl -c /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf reread

      # Update supervisord in cache without restarting all services
      supervisorctl -c /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf update

      # Start/Restart celeryd through supervisord
      supervisorctl -c /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf restart django-celery-worker


container_commands:
  01_celery_tasks_run:
    command: "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/run_supervised_celeryd.sh"

option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: myapp/wsgi.py
  aws:elb:listener:443:
    SSLCertificateId: arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:349705394408:certificate/5e94d3d2-039a-4ffc-bf7e-06995dc65fc9
    ListenerProtocol: HTTPS
    InstancePort: 80
```

What have I got wrong?